# errors in JMeter log when using split method

Tags: split, jmeter, beanshell

how to avoid these erros in the log? The split method seem to work fine. it splits the string into 4 vars like it shoud.

i am using a BeanShell PostProcessor with the following script:

```
${__split(${VAR},VAR)}

${VAR} is something like bla.bla,123,12345,12345
VAR_n=4
VAR_1=bla.bla
VAR_2=123
VAR_3=12345
VAR_4=12345
VAR_5=null
```

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html 
JMeter Log from GUI Mode:

- 2017/01/19 18:36:14 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``longhaireddachshund.net,770,5007745,211092;'' Encountered "," at line 1, column 24.
- 2017/01/19 18:36:14 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``longhaireddachshund.net,770,5007745,211092;'' Encountered "," at line 1, column 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the String literal or a variable containing the string to the split function.

`${__split(${VAR},VAR)}` will be replaced by `${__split(bla.bla,123,12345,12345,VAR)}` - it makes it throw the error.

Instead do like this as shown here.

`${__split("${VAR}",VAR)}` which will make it look like `${__split("bla.bla,123,12345,12345",VAR)}` - you would not face any issues.

Comment: the errors disappears but after i added the quotes. VAR_1 is '"bla.bla'

Comment: i just realised that a simple "Regular Expression Extractor" is all i need. Reference Name: VAR
Regular Expression: (.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)
Template: $1$$2$$3$$4$

VAR_g1 = bla.bla